# Spring Security oauth2 client - How does one obtain a JWT token

Tags: spring-security, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use **spring-security-oauth2-client** and **spring-security-oauth2-jose** to authenticate against Azure AD and get JWT tokens.
The login part works but the token that I receive is not a JWT. Here's my configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .oauth2Login()
    .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/azure")
    .userInfoEndpoint()
    .oidcUserService(oidcUserService);
}

}
```

After authentication, I retrieve the token from the security context as follows :

```
OAuth2AuthenticationToken authentication = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
            authentication.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId()
            ,authentication.getName()
            ).getAccessToken();
```

I get a Bearer token that looks like:

"AQABAAAAAADXzZ3ifr-GRbDT45zNSEFElTInSJQ19I2zONWkrBPgoKf8MCYL_z_IzU2lmF_ZadgBMdCr337faL0bpqHAzmFhsxq8peWUX7iYeTLbmcHDIdCR617VSKKHISLn_AiXhNr9rF6AMSrQTzdV2mKhEVlycTXlHUsZkA-gMA4z4FQFQMYkFNcLKqr7b-NewnV07lbG55joRIkcCMDrM1s4X8mRcJpRF6ek1yNSpveFmlbkrt3cXPUqtDe5EWI_5gfuGEVIon57LFLos_JtcQWSL6CTrUlY8EuF8MVuwJpTNG3OR80ikK7ycH_dXFCYmYDRrtTbFkf3R61aDSnqEUe2IIl2T8QdqWqH65ykSVooG6uIi5KsRK9zXPRuRuC_XC5w6SCcGionQYIgSEp-kCtIzlfHIBRK2o_CpjYVMBdmbfIkCvFoTGGGAvpOP1_MkgVeBiQzYFg8m_dn_roXFF17oBhCdYrZ2Y41_-GngLU3VJj4ltFIxzRziH6CZ2aFl1N3MwzIUcTiN6Ci0oyODTsSNDPc2zvxg609SjEqrO-6Xp0LMEwiOgY5L5rrcLA5d4LN-Xq9NiG0KqybZPU7wW0AHNA2Nw7bSg1Cle0ReaBU4ANbkjHxYeQJf65-ONNMGdfkV8xlKtRXZoiOBFip87Z72cS4NjLjM3x9_Qk9MQ5eGQTNj4fHCzJp9ukcjQ1MSUol_VIgAA
"

Which is then rejected by the Microsoft Graph API. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your Bearer token does not look like an `access_token`. It looks like an `authorization_code`. Please verify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. What you had was the authorization code returned. To get the access token, use the following:

```
public void getToken(OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken, @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "idToken") OidcIdToken idToken) {

System.out.println(idToken);

}
```

Comment: @EdouardZerbo: I need exactly same thing. But how do I call this method ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the id token from the Authentication object. You need to cast the authentication.principal to OidcUser. The OidcUser gives you complete details of the user.

```
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = 
                clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                        oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                        oauthToken.getName());


    if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser) {
            OidcUser principal = ((OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
            idToken = principal.getIdToken().getTokenValue();
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly how tokens should be extracted in OIDC!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @govind's answer, this is the way to get an OIDC token in modern functional Java:

```
public Optional<String> getCurrentToken() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
        .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
        .map(Authentication::getPrincipal)
        .filter(OidcUser.class::isInstance)
        .map(OidcUser.class::cast)
        .map(OidcUser::getIdToken)
        .map(OidcIdToken::getTokenValue);
}
```